# Differentiable varieties

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry

Test that the cylinder $C = \left\lbrace \left( x, y, z \right) \in \mathbb{R}^3 \; / \; x^2 + y^2 = 1; \; z > 0 \right\rbrace $ it is a differentiable variety; from the parameterizations  $ \; a \left( u, v \right) = \left( cos \; u, \; seno \; u, \; v \right) \; $ y $ \; \beta \left( u, v \right) = \left( seno \; u, \; cos \; u, \; v\right) $. 
SOLUCIÓN
$a\left( u, v \right) = \left( cos(u), sin(u), v \right) $
$(u, v) = \varphi (cos(u), sin(u), v)$
So:
$\varphi(p_1, p_2, p_3) = \left( arctg \left( \dfrac{p_2}{p_1} \right) , p_3 \right) $
$\psi (q_1, q_2, q_3) = \left( cot \left( \dfrac{q_2}{q_1} \right) , q_3 \right) $
$(\varphi \circ \psi^{-1}) (u, v) = \varphi (\psi^{-1}(u, v))$

Please make a comment about my solution to the exercise, suggest me if something needs to be corrected.

Comment: In English we speak of "differentiable manifolds", not "differentiable varieties".